# Múltiplos schemas no banco de dados Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Boa tarde pessoal, estou refazendo um sistema e adotei o Laravel 5. Neste sistema tenho vários schemas no banco de dados e a solução que encontrei foi trabalhar com uma conexão para cada schema, da seguinte forma:

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'schema1',
        ],

        'pgsql2' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'schema2',
        ],
```

Teria alguma outra forma de fazer isso ?﻿

Answer (score 7):

A melhor forma para trabalhar com bancos múltiplos no laravel é desta forma:

No arquivo de configuração você poderá definir todos os drivers a ser utilizado e os bancos:

```
return array(

'default' => 'mysql',

'connections' => array(

    # Our primary database connection
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host1',
        'database'  => 'database1',
        'username'  => 'user1',
        'password'  => 'pass1'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    # Our secondary database connection
    'mysql2' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host2',
        'database'  => 'database2',
        'username'  => 'user2',
        'password'  => 'pass2'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Após isso será preciso você definir em seus models qual conexão a ser utilizada, como por exemplo no uso do Eloquent será possível configurar apenas definindo no escopo da classe:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql2';
```

Desta maneira todas as consultas/alterações serão feitas através das configurações `mysql2`.

Também é possível definir a conexão fora da class, e sim dentro do escopo da função, ou seja, quando você quiser executar X função em Y database:

```
public function method()
{
    $this->setConnection('mysql2');

    $this = $someModel->find(1);

    return $something;
}
```

Também é possível trabalhar fora do eloquent desta forma:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...);
```

Assim o seu sistema estará pronto para receber mult-conexões. Show, né?

Abraços!

Fontes: http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html

Comment: Existe uma maneira de criar dinamicamente os drivers e os bancos? Por exemplo, o usuário se cadastra no sistema e é criada um schema somente para ele. E assim sucessivamente, sem que o desenvolvedor ou a pessoa responsável se preocupe em adicionar manualmente. +1

Comment: opa! Vamos lá... Para criar as databases você precisará das migrations: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations onde para criar você pode chamar o comando por um controller http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/run-artisan-commands-form-route-or-controller. Depois de criar você a base de dados você poderá armazenar na base principal o usuário e o nome do banco dele, quando ele acessar rota para ele http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing você configura a base dele. Toda vez que fizer operação do model você pode pegar por a db dele na session.

Comment: Exemplo para você aqui: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l5-multiple-databases-based-on-subdomein