# Problemas visualização dos Dados Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Sou iniciante no Laravel e estou tentando trazer dados de um BD com multiplos schemas do Postgresql com Laravel 5.1 e está me trazendo um erro

Qual configuração deve fazer para o model acessar corretamente a tabela daquele schema?

Diretamente pelo postgres escreveria a consulta dessa forma:

```
 SELECT * FROM cadastro.escolaridade  
 SELECT * FROM schema.tabela
```

> ErrorException in TesteController.php line 13: Use of undefined
>   constant cadastro - assumed 'cadastro'

**Database.php**

```
'pgsql' => [
'driver'   => 'pgsql',
'host'     => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
'charset'  => 'utf8',
'prefix'   => '',
'schema'   => 'public',
],
```

**Model**

```
<?php


namespace App\Models\Programas;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cadastro extends Model
{

}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Models\Programas\Cadastro;


 class TesteController extends Controller
 {


public function getIndex()
{
    $escolaridade = cadastro.escolaridade::all();


    return view('programas.escrituras.index', compact('escolaridade'));


}
```

**View**

```
@forelse($escolaridade as $descricao)

<p><b>Grau de Escolaridade:</b>{{$descricao->descricao}}</p>

@empty
    <p>Nenhum Grau Cadastrado!</p>

    @endforelse
```

Comment: `Cadastro::all()` retorna algo? `cadastro.escolaridade::all();` não se refere a classe nem a um schema. Talvez `Cadastro` tenha uma propriedade chamada `$escolaridade`.

Comment: Talvez [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82557/91) possa ajudar.

Comment: Vou dar minha opnião marcando a pergunta dele. (Esse erro não pode ser reproduzido, tal tal e tal)

Comment: O erro não faz parte desses arquivos, vc está recebendo a mensagem, mas o problema vem de outro lugar... é melhor você descobrir o problema, use xdebug ou PHPUnit para testar suas classes. Ou algo mais simples, como `die();` `var_dump()` e `print_r()`.

Comment: @IvanFerrer a sintaxe `cadastro.escolaridade::all();` que está no `TesteController` é inválida, me parece que ele quer saber como fazer model consultar um banco em um ou multiplos schemas.

Comment: Pela lógica do erro, ele não está encontrando a constante, dê uma [olhada aqui](http://www.codedungeon.org/2013/09/10/getting-started-with-laravel-and-postgresql/).

Comment: Já verificou no [site do laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries) ?

Comment: No PHP não existe essa sintaxe com ponto no PHP, pelo menos não que eu saiba: `cadastro.escolaridade::all()` o que é existe é isso: `{string1.string2}` ou isso `$cadastro->escolaridade::all()`.

Comment: Tirei o negativo que eu tinha dado. Mas acho que a pergunta deve ser reelaborada.

Comment: Talvez o que ele queira fazer seja alguma coisa assim: 
  `$escolaridade = Cadastro->escolaridade::all();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21099291/1342547), você deve definir o schema no atributo `$table` do seu model.

```
class Cadastro extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cadastro.escolaridade';
}
```

Depois pode chamar normalmente,

```
$escolaridade = Cadastro::all();
```

Comment: Assim também dá. Do jeito que eu fiz você pode usar tanto dois bancos, como também bancos de outras conexões, como também banco de outras SQL. O Laravel 4 já é top, o 5 então nem se fale. +1. Essa daí eu não sabia :)

Comment: A Forma que o @rray declarou deu certo!

Answer (score 1):

Esse trecho do código está errado

```
$escolaridade = cadastro.escolaridade::all();
```

Por acaso você vem de outra linguagem e está tentando acessar membros de classes ou objetos?

O seu código indica que você está tentando concatenar uma constante `cadastro` com o resultado trazido por `escolaridade::all()` (que por usa vez é convertido para `Json`, já que está concatenando). Como a constante não existe, o erro é gerado.

É assim que o PHP está entendendo seu código. Então, se não é o resultado desejado, vocÊ tem que alterá-lo.

## Múltiplos Schemas

No Laravel você poderia utilizar mais de uma conexão para resolver esse problema.

Por exemplo, você pode definir sua configuração assim:

```
return [
    
    'default' => 'pgsql',

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'database' => 'schema_1',
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ],

    'pgsql_2' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'database' => 'schema_2',
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ]
];
```

E no model que quer usar outro schema (diferente do que está em `default`), você pode defini-lo no model.

Exemplo com schema padrão definido na configuração:

```
namespace App\Model\Schema1;

class Pessoa {}
```

Exmeplo com schema padrão definido no model

```
namespace App\Model\Schema2;

class TabelaQualquer
{
       protected $connection = 'pgsql_2';
}
```

Assim, você está informando ao model que estará utilizando outra configuração de conexão com o banco de dados para ele. No caso, você utiliza os mesmos dados de conexão, alterando apenas o banco.

Comment: A pergunta é valida, nos postgres uma banco de dados pode ter varias 'divisões' logicas, que são chamadas de schemas, no sql para fazer uma consulta fica, `select * from schema.tabela` ou `select * from cadastro.escolaridade`. Como laravel resolve esse problema(acesso a multiplos schemas?

Comment: @rray, mas tem um erro de sintaxe sim. Isso é que causa o erro. E o laravel aceita pg sim

Comment: Não precisa nenhuma configuração extra?o schema onde ficam as tabelas geralmente é o `public` mas algumas pessoas criam outros, outro dia vi essa mesma(ou quase) pergunta, achei curioso.

Comment: @rray, atualizado. Vi o que ele precisava. No laravel você pode usar quantas conexões diferentes quiser (5 por exemplo). Basta configurar cada uma e definir quais models vão fazer isso. No laravel 5, como foi implementado os  namespaces, achei justo fazer como fiz no meu exemplo, colocando um namespace pra cada schema.

Comment: Se entendeu o ponto da questão blz :), um schema não é uma conexão :P mas se é assim que o framework resolve o problema, bola pra frente. Me pergunto como fica o relacionamento entre uma tabela de um schema com outra de outra através do orm :P. +1 pela resposta e pelo comentário de cima.

Comment: @rray se eu falei alguma besteira, por favor, corriga minha resposta :D rsrsrsrsrs

Comment: @rray dá pra fazer uma foreign key de um banco para o outro (claro, na mesma conexão). Não sei se é gambiarra :#

Comment: @WallaceMaxters No meu BD Postgres tenho 17 Schemas não sei se essa forma criando varias conexões seria muito viável

Comment: Então não faça assim. Apenas guarde o conhecimento ;). É melhor fazer igual  o @rray