# Consulta case-sensitive no sql server com laravel 5.4

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Estou efetuando uma consulta ao banco de dados (sql server) para validação de usuário e senha com o laravel 5.4 mas, a consulta está sendo executada como case-insensitive.

No banco de dados está:

> pwd = Aa12A

O input recebe:

> password = aa12a

O resultado é:

> pwd == password

Consulta:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where('acc', $request->input('account'))
    ->where('pwd', $request->input('password'))
    ->first();
```

Como mudar isso?

Comment: Qual é a codificação/collation do banco?

Comment: É SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Tentei alterar diretamente no banco de dados, mas não está aceitando a troca da collation.

Comment: Sabe que Ci significa case insensitive né?

Comment: Sim. E é exatamente por isso que perguntei, para saber se existe algum meio de determinar isso na consulta do próprio laravel, já que não consegui alterar no banco de dados, pois existe uma restrição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se é complicado a comparação de senhas pelo SQL server, você pode fazer pelo PHP.

```
$result = DB::table('users')
->where('acc', $request->input('account'))
->first();

if ($result && $result->pwd === $request->input('password')) {
      // Senhas conferem
}
```

Ainda assim, creio que seja possível definir na configuração de banco de dados. Por exemplo, vou definir duas configurações iguais, porém com a `collation` diferente.

```
[
    'sqlserver' => [
        'driver'    => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'      => 'host',
        'database'  => '',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'collation' =>  'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',
        'charset'   =>  'latin1'
    ],

    'sqlserver-case-sensitive' => [
        'driver'    => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'      => 'host',
        'database'  => '',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'collation' =>  'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS',
        'charset'   =>  'latin1'
    ]
]
```

Para usar a `collation` da segunda configuração de conexão, basta fazer assim:

```
DB::connection('sqlserver-case-sensitive')->table('users')
    ->where('acc', $request->input('account'))
    ->where('pwd', $request->input('password'))
   ->first();
```

Leituras recomendadas:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#using-multiple-database-connections
- [Múltiplos schemas no banco de dados Laravel 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82557/m%C3%BAltiplos-schemas-no-banco-de-dados-laravel-5)

Comment: Pensei nessa possibilidade, mas preferi perguntar para ver se existe algum outro meio para "economizar" código. haha. Mas obrigado! =)

Comment: @Getulio estou editando, tem sim... Eu não manjo de SqlServer, mas você pode usar a opção COLLATE na consulta

Comment: Eu também não (kk), mas vou procurar sobre. Obrigado!

Comment: @Getulio agora acho que melhorou, acho que a última opção é o que você precisa!

Comment: Tentei, mas não funcionou. Vou ter que fazer pelo php mesmo! Melhor do que ficar quebrando a cabeça. xD  Obrigado pela ajuda!