# Como Trabalhar com mais de uma Tabela no Laravel

Tags: laravel-eloquent

Bom dia.

Estou tentando utilizar 2 tabelas mysql, como se fossem 2 schemas, porem não estou conseguindo, tentei os exemplos:

https://www.bugginhoacademy.com.br/blog/trabalhando-com-mais-de-um-banco-de-dados-no-laravel/

[Múltiplos schemas no banco de dados Laravel 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82557/m%C3%BAltiplos-schemas-no-banco-de-dados-laravel-5)

Mais não deu certo, podem me ajudar?

**Arquivo `.env`**

```
DB_CONNECTION=banco1
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=banco1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION2=banco2
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=banco2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Conexoes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Conexoes extends Model
{
    //
    protected $connection = 'gps';
}
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Rastreamento;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Conexoes\Positions;
use App\Rastreamento\Markers;
use Mapper;

class PosiceosController extends Controller
{
  private $positions;

  public function index(){
    $this->setConnection('banco2');

   $registros= $this->tabela->all();

}
```

Comment: Coloque o código que está a utilizar e o erro que está a aparecer

Comment: .env = DB_CONNECTION=banco1
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=banco1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION2=banco2
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=banco2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Model:

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece pra você?

Comment: Ele só encontra a primeira conexão e não encontra a tabela por que ela esta na segunda conexão

Comment: você disse que seguiu o exemplo do primeiro link, mas está faltando código no seu exemplo. Seu código está exatamente igual ao do link 1? Outra coisa a versão do exemplo foi no laravel 5.4. É a mesma que a sua?

Comment: Sim e  a mesma 5.4